# Open file with extension .fig with java

Tags: java, file

I have a project in Java where I want to make a GUI that optimizes functions.

In order to give the user an idea about the optimum of the function I simply draw it in `matlab`.

So now the problem is to save the 3D figure that I made with `matlab` and make a button that when a user clicks on it gives access to the figure with `matlab` (.fig file).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When you say you want the user to have "access to the figure with `matlab` (.fig file)" do you mean you want to show it in Windows Explorer/Finder/nautilus? Or do you want to open the file itself in MATLAB?

Comment: open the file itself in matlab problem resolved thanks anyway